# Google Calendar, is it possible for the calendar owner to show free times to a 3rd party viewer and allow them to submit bookings?

Tags: google-calendar-api

In an online booking system scenario, the business owner has an instance of the google calendar where they have booked appointments and free times.

Is it possible for another user (customer) to log on to their customer portal, see an instance of the business owner's calendar, select a free time and submit an appointment booking, thus making that slot appear as busy?

Is it also possible to hide details of other bookings from the customers view of the calendar so that they only see that a time is available or not and not see any other customer information i.e who has booked other appointments?

Apologies for such basic questions - I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not basic and if you consider permissions and user privacy what you are talking about is quite complex.

Lets take user one bob.  Bob has created a calendar on your system where he has stored his data.   Now we have user number two Jane she would like to invite Bob to a meeting at 10 to do this she needs to check and see if Bob is free.   So she checks your system and it turns out Bob has another meeting scheduled with Mark at 10 title "fire Jane."

You need to remember that Bobs calendar is his private information he needs to be the one to decided who he wants to see the data in his calendar.